# force summary() to report the number of NA's even if none

Tags: r, na, summary

I have many numeric vectors, some have NA's, some don't. Here is an example with two vectors:

```
x1 <- c(1,2,3,2,2,4)
summary(x1)
 Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
1.000   2.000   2.000   2.333   2.750   4.000 

x2 <- c(1,2,3,2,2,4,NA)
summary(x2)
 Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
1.000   2.000   2.000   2.333   2.750   4.000       1
```

In the end, I want to `rbind` all the `summary`'s:

```
rbind(summary(x1), summary(x2))
     Min. 1st Qu. Median  Mean 3rd Qu. Max. NA's
[1,]    1       2      2 2.333    2.75    4    1
[2,]    1       2      2 2.333    2.75    4    1
Warning message:
In rbind(summary(x1), summary(x2)) :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

Is there a way to force `summary` to count NA's without error nor warning?

All my trials failed:

```
summary(x1, na.rm=FALSE)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   2.000   2.000   2.333   2.750   4.000 
summary(x1, useNA="always")
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   2.000   2.000   2.333   2.750   4.000 
summary(addNA(x1))
   1    2    3    4 <NA> 
   1    3    1    1    0
```

I also tried the following, but it is a bit of a hack:

```
tmp <- rbind(summary(x1[complete.cases(x1)]), summary(x2[complete.cases(x2)]))
tmp <- cbind(tmp, c(sum(is.na(x1)), sum(is.na(x2))))
colnames(tmp)[ncol(tmp)] <- "NA's"
tmp
     Min. 1st Qu. Median  Mean 3rd Qu. Max. NA's
[1,]    1       2      2 2.333    2.75    4    0
[2,]    1       2      2 2.333    2.75    4    1
```

Comment: See also `rbind.fill` from `plyr`. Note: coercion to `data.frame` required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not found a way to force summary to display NA's. However, you could write a custom function that returns what you want:

```
my_summary <- function(v){
  if(!any(is.na(v))){
    res <- c(summary(v),"NA's"=0)
  } else{
    res <- summary(v)
  }
  return(res)
}
```

Comment: better to use `!any(is.na(v))`

Comment: edited. For my own understanding, can you explain why?

Comment: more efficient and it does the same thing. especially since the output of `is.na` is logical already, it's best to stick with the logical operators `any`, `all`, etc

Answer (score 1):

Because the problem is that you are combining vectors of different lengths you can assign the length of the longest to the shortest. When you combine them, this will generate NAs for the missing data that we can easily replace with zeros.

```
s1 <- summary(x1)
s2 <- summary(x2)
length(s1) <- length(s2)
s <- rbind(s2,s1)
s[is.na(s)] <- 0
```

Output:

```
   Min. 1st Qu. Median  Mean 3rd Qu. Max. NA's
s2    1       2      2 2.333    2.75    4    1
s1    1       2      2 2.333    2.75    4    0
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions that were given before ignore the fact that summary() also works for data.frames and matrices. I would usually handle this by recursive function definition although the result is not exactly the same as is with the original summary() function.

```
summaryna <- function(x, ...) {
  # Recursive function definition in case of matrix or data.frame.
  if(is.matrix(x)) {
    return(apply(x,2,function(x)summaryna(x, ...)))
  } else if (is.data.frame(x)) {
    return(sapply(x,function(x)summaryna(x, ...)))
  }
  # This is the actual function.
  sum <- summary(x, ...)
  if(length(sum)<7)    sum <- c(sum,"NA's"=0)
  return(sum)
}
```